# When calling "context.AttachTo" - The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm having difficulty making a change to an entity object through a new context. I've had this work plenty of times before, but in this instance I'm getting the old "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed" exception.

Here's my quick edit/save code:

```
private void SaveChanges()
{
    using (var context = new Manticore.ManticoreContext(Global.ManticoreClient))
    {
        **context.AttachTo("Users", Global.LoggedInUser);**
        Global.LoggedInUser.FirstName = this.FirstNameText.Text;
        Global.LoggedInUser.LastName = this.LastNameText.Text;
        Global.LoggedInUser.Email = this.EmailText.Text;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The Global.LoggedInUser property (which is instantiated):

```
public static Manticore.User LoggedInUser
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUser"] as Manticore.User;
    }

    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInUser"] = value;
    }
}
```

And the kicker is here's a quick unit test which works (no assert right now, but no exception being thrown):

```
    private User _testUser;

    private TestInstanceBucket _testBucket;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        using (var context = new Manticore.ManticoreContext())
        {
            this._testBucket = new TestInstanceBucket(context);
            this._testUser = this._testBucket.TestUser;
            context.AddObject("Users", this._testUser);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void User_ShouldBeAbleToChangeDetails()
    {
        using (var context = new ManticoreContext())
        {
            context.AttachTo("Users", this._testUser);
            this._testUser.FirstName = "New";
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Like I say, I've done code like this before and it's been fine. Have I been lucking out, or could storing the entity in the session be causing problems?

**Update**

I've moved the code from global to a pagebase class which the page using SaveChanges() inherits. Same problem so it rules our static classes/methods and storing the entity in the session somehow causing problems.

**Update**

So, after several hours of banging my head against a wall, I have a fix that's fairly simple if annoying. After the initial fetch of the user I now call

```
context.Detach(user);
```

I can only assume it's something to do with how fast the context is being disposed with garbage collection in ASP.NET compared to in the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my EF experience this issue always seems to occur when the entity is still linked to the old context.  I believe it is safest to always just re-load the entity using the new context (query on PK).  I know it is not the most efficient but it avoids this problem.

I took a look at this page before answering, if you haven't tried some of its suggestions you might give them a go: [EF Add/Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592676).

Comment: I'd rather avoid the road of refetching if I can, especially when the test case is working with the same method. Incidentally, I tried to make the LoggedInUser get do a new fetch and was getting the same problem. There's something about that class that it doesn't like. Static methods?